Hardware error when using kernel newer than 6.5.0
On Xubuntu 24.04.1, using any kernel newer than 6.5.0-28-generic #29-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Mar 28 23:46:48 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
results in the following error message from dmesg | grep Error:
[    0.624470] mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged
[    0.624479] mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 2: Machine Check: 0 Bank 5: 8c20004000101119
[    0.624508] mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC a3cc8da24 ADDR 106d39c40 MISC 7c21 
[    0.624530] mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0:20655 TIME 1729460105 SOCKET 0 APIC 4 microcode 7
[    0.852074] RAS: Correctable Errors collector initialized.```````

Here is the output from lshw
x201
    description: Notebook
    product: 3680D79
    vendor: LENOVO
    version: ThinkPad X201
    serial: R95KCPA
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.6 dmi-2.6 smp vsyscall32
    configuration: administrator_password=disabled boot=normal chassis=notebook family=ThinkPad X201 frontpanel_password=unknown keyboard_password=disabled power-on_password=disabled uuid=6032c388-b698-df11-91a5-d149bcf4b37b
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: 3680D79
       vendor: LENOVO
       physical id: 0
       version: Not Available
       serial: 1ZHWL07R5BU
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: LENOVO
          physical id: 0
          version: 6QET70WW (1.40 )
          date: 10/11/2012
          size: 128KiB
          capacity: 8MiB
          capabilities: pci pcmcia pnp upgrade shadowing escd cdboot bootselect edd int13floppy720 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer int10video acpi usb biosbootspecification
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU       M 520  @ 2.40GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 6
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: 6.37.5
          slot: None
          size: 2660MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 133MHz
          capabilities: fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes lahf_lm pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow flexpriority ept vpid dtherm ida arat vnmi flush_l1d cpufreq
          configuration: cores=2 enabledcores=2 microcode=7 threads=4
        *-cache:0
             description: L1 cache
             physical id: a
             slot: Internal L1 Cache
             size: 32KiB
             capacity: 32KiB
             capabilities: asynchronous internal write-through data
             configuration: level=1
        *-cache:1
             description: L2 cache
             physical id: b
             slot: Internal L2 Cache
             size: 256KiB
             capacity: 256KiB
             capabilities: burst internal write-through unified
             configuration: level=2
        *-cache:2
             description: L3 cache
             physical id: c
             slot: Internal L3 Cache
             size: 3MiB
             capacity: 8MiB
             capabilities: burst internal write-back
             configuration: level=3
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 2a
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 8GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1066 MHz (0.9 ns)
             product: 16JSF51264HZ-1G1D1
             vendor: Micron Technology
             physical id: 0
             serial: E16F7425
             slot: DIMM 1
             size: 4GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1066MHz (0.9ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1066 MHz (0.9 ns)
             product: 16JSF51264HZ-1G1D1
             vendor: Micron Technology
             physical id: 1
             serial: E16F7424
             slot: DIMM 2
             size: 4GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1066MHz (0.9ns)
     *-pci:0
          description: Host bridge
          product: Core Processor DRAM Controller
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 02
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
        *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             logical name: /dev/fb0
             version: 02
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
             configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 resolution=1280,800
             resources: irq:28 memory:f2000000-f23fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:1800(size=8) memory:c0000-dffff
        *-communication
             description: Communication controller
             product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 16
             bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
             version: 06
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=mei_me latency=0
             resources: irq:26 memory:f2727800-f272780f
        *-network
             description: Ethernet interface
             product: 82577LM Gigabit Network Connection
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 19
             bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
             logical name: enp0s25
             version: 06
             serial: f0:de:f1:07:dd:23
             capacity: 1Gbit/s
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
             configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=6.5.0-28-generic firmware=0.12-1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
             resources: irq:24 memory:f2500000-f251ffff memory:f2525000-f2525fff ioport:1820(size=32)
        *-usb:0
             description: USB controller
             product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1a
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1a.0
             version: 06
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
             resources: irq:23 memory:f2728000-f27283ff
           *-usbhost
                product: EHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 6.5.0-28-generic ehci_hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@1
                logical name: usb1
                version: 6.05
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=3 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb
                   description: USB hub
                   product: Integrated Rate Matching Hub
                   vendor: Intel Corp.
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: usb@1:1
                   version: 0.00
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=hub slots=6 speed=480Mbit/s
                 *-usb:0
                      description: Bluetooth wireless interface
                      product: Broadcom Bluetooth Device
                      vendor: Broadcom Corp
                      physical id: 4
                      bus info: usb@1:1.4
                      version: 3.60
                      serial: 78DD08AAEB06
                      capabilities: bluetooth usb-2.00
                      configuration: driver=btusb speed=12Mbit/s
                 *-usb:1
                      description: Video
                      product: Integrated Camera
                      vendor: Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd.
                      physical id: 6
                      bus info: usb@1:1.6
                      version: 72.28
                      capabilities: usb-2.00
                      configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=200mA speed=480Mbit/s
        *-multimedia
             description: Audio device
             product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1b
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
             logical name: card0
             logical name: /dev/snd/controlC0
             logical name: /dev/snd/hwC0D0
             logical name: /dev/snd/hwC0D3
             logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D0c
             logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D0p
             logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D3p
             version: 06
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
             resources: irq:29 memory:f2520000-f2523fff
           *-input:0
                product: HDA Intel MID Mic
                physical id: 0
                logical name: input13
                logical name: /dev/input/event11
           *-input:1
                product: HDA Intel MID Dock Mic
                physical id: 1
                logical name: input14
                logical name: /dev/input/event12
           *-input:2
                product: HDA Intel MID Dock Headphone
                physical id: 2
                logical name: input15
                logical name: /dev/input/event13
           *-input:3
                product: HDA Intel MID Headphone
                physical id: 3
                logical name: input16
                logical name: /dev/input/event14
           *-input:4
                product: HDA Intel MID HDMI/DP,pcm=3
                physical id: 4
                logical name: input17
                logical name: /dev/input/event15
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: 06
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:20
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 4
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.3
             version: 06
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:23 ioport:2000(size=4096) memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:f2800000(size=1048576)
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 5
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.4
             version: 06
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:20 memory:f2400000-f24fffff
           *-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: Centrino Advanced-N 6200
                vendor: Intel Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
                logical name: wlp2s0
                version: 35
                serial: 00:27:10:25:82:d0
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=6.5.0-28-generic firmware=9.221.4.1 build 25532 6000-4.uc ip=192.168.1.22 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
                resources: irq:27 memory:f2400000-f2401fff
        *-usb:1
             description: USB controller
             product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.0
             version: 06
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
             resources: irq:19 memory:f2728400-f27287ff
           *-usbhost
                product: EHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 6.5.0-28-generic ehci_hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@2
                logical name: usb2
                version: 6.05
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=3 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb
                   description: USB hub
                   product: Integrated Rate Matching Hub
                   vendor: Intel Corp.
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: usb@2:1
                   version: 0.00
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=hub slots=8 speed=480Mbit/s
                 *-usb
                      description: Keyboard
                      product: Chicony 2.4G Multimedia Wireless Kit Consumer Control
                      vendor: Chicony
                      physical id: 2
                      bus info: usb@2:1.2
                      logical name: input10
                      logical name: /dev/input/event7
                      logical name: /dev/input/mouse0
                      logical name: input6
                      logical name: /dev/input/event4
                      logical name: input6::capslock
                      logical name: input6::numlock
                      logical name: input6::scrolllock
                      logical name: input7
                      logical name: /dev/input/event5
                      logical name: input9
                      logical name: /dev/input/event6
                      version: 1.00
                      capabilities: usb-2.00 usb
                      configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=98mA speed=2Mbit/s
        *-pci:3
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1e
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1e.0
             version: a6
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci subtractive_decode bus_master cap_list
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: QM57 Chipset LPC Interface Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 06
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=lpc_ich latency=0
             resources: irq:0
           *-pnp00:00
                product: PnP device PNP0c01
                physical id: 0
                capabilities: pnp
                configuration: driver=system
           *-pnp00:01
                product: PnP device PNP0c02
                physical id: 1
                capabilities: pnp
                configuration: driver=system
           *-pnp00:02
                product: PnP device PNP0b00
                physical id: 2
                capabilities: pnp
                configuration: driver=rtc_cmos
           *-pnp00:03
                product: PnP device PNP0303
                physical id: 3
                capabilities: pnp
                configuration: driver=i8042 kbd
           *-pnp00:04
                product: PnP device IBM3780
                vendor: IBM Brasil
                physical id: 4
                capabilities: pnp
                configuration: driver=i8042 aux
        *-sata
             description: SATA controller
             product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 6 port SATA AHCI Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
             logical name: scsi0
             version: 06
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: sata msi pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list emulated
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
             resources: irq:25 ioport:1860(size=8) ioport:1814(size=4) ioport:1818(size=8) ioport:1810(size=4) ioport:1840(size=32) memory:f2727000-f27277ff
           *-disk
                description: ATA Disk
                product: KINGSTON SA400S3
                physical id: 0.0.0
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
                logical name: /dev/sda
                version: B1D1
                serial: 50026B7782D898B8
                size: 111GiB (120GB)
                capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
                configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=bb1a5f84-719c-4dc6-8241-fcb127f17fbf logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
              *-volume:0
                   description: BIOS Boot partition
                   vendor: EFI
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,1
                   logical name: /dev/sda1
                   serial: eafb3bf9-2af9-4efb-a575-f7f549fa6a33
                   capacity: 1023KiB
                   capabilities: nofs
              *-volume:1
                   description: Windows FAT volume
                   vendor: mkfs.fat
                   physical id: 2
                   bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,2
                   logical name: /dev/sda2
                   logical name: /boot/efi
                   version: FAT32
                   serial: 3b0c-95fb
                   size: 510MiB
                   capacity: 512MiB
                   capabilities: boot fat initialized
                   configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat mount.fstype=vfat mount.options=rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro state=mounted
              *-volume:2
                   description: LVM Physical Volume
                   vendor: Linux
                   physical id: 3
                   bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,3
                   logical name: /dev/sda3
                   serial: PVPukD-vpCY-D8ft-WBhD-Y1fG-dulF-wTjCaY
                   size: 111GiB
                   capabilities: multi lvm2
        *-serial
             description: SMBus
             product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             version: 06
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: driver=i801_smbus latency=0
             resources: irq:23 memory:f2728800-f27288ff ioport:1880(size=32)
        *-generic
             description: Signal processing controller
             product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Thermal Subsystem
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.6
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
             version: 06
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi cap_list
             configuration: driver=intel ips latency=0
             resources: irq:19 memory:f2526000-f2526fff
     *-pci:1
          description: Host bridge
          product: Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 101
          bus info: pci@0000:ff:00.0
          version: 02
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:2
          description: Host bridge
          product: Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 102
          bus info: pci@0000:ff:00.1
          version: 02
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:3
          description: Host bridge
          product: Core Processor QPI Link 0
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 103
          bus info: pci@0000:ff:02.0
          version: 02
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:4
          description: Host bridge
          product: 1st Generation Core i3/5/7 Processor QPI Physical 0
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 104
          bus info: pci@0000:ff:02.1
          version: 02
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:5
          description: Host bridge
          product: 1st Generation Core i3/5/7 Processor Reserved
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 105
          bus info: pci@0000:ff:02.2
          version: 02
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:6
          description: Host bridge
          product: 1st Generation Core i3/5/7 Processor Reserved
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 106
          bus info: pci@0000:ff:02.3
          version: 02
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
  *-battery
       product: 42T4694
       vendor: SANYO
       physical id: 1
       slot: Rear
       capacity: 86580mWh
       configuration: voltage=11.1V
  *-input:0
       product: Lid Switch
       physical id: 2
       logical name: input0
       logical name: /dev/input/event0
       capabilities: platform
  *-input:1
       product: Sleep Button
       physical id: 3
       logical name: input1
       logical name: /dev/input/event1
       capabilities: platform
  *-input:2
       product: ThinkPad Extra Buttons
       physical id: 4
       logical name: input11
       logical name: /dev/input/event9
       capabilities: platform
  *-input:3
       product: Video Bus
       physical id: 5
       logical name: input12
       logical name: /dev/input/event10
       capabilities: platform
  *-input:4
       product: Power Button
       physical id: 6
       logical name: input2
       logical name: /dev/input/event2
       capabilities: platform
  *-input:5
       product: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
       physical id: 7
       logical name: input3
       logical name: /dev/input/event3
       logical name: input3::capslock
       logical name: input3::numlock
       logical name: input3::scrolllock
       capabilities: i8042
  *-input:6
       product: TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint
       physical id: 8
       logical name: input5
       logical name: /dev/input/event8
       logical name: /dev/input/mouse1
       capabilities: i8042

Any suggestions, other than sticking with an older kernel?

Take a look at the following link which details something similar. https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=266210 It highlights two things: - Firstly does this just happen during the boot process? Second does the BIOS show any problems with the hardware.

It doesn't seem to happen during the boot process- eventually, usually within a minute or two of logging into the laptop it will freeze/lock up, and that's the only error message I've been able to find. I ran memtest86+ and it came back fine.
